# Find elements in list

Tags: python, list

```py
from itertools import permutations as pm

perm = pm([1, 2, 3, 4])
pm_list = []

for i in list(perm):
    pm_list.append(i)

print(pm_list)
print(pm_list[0])
```

gives me:

```
[(1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 4, 3), ... ]
(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

How can I work with the numbers in the second row `(1, 2, 3, 4)`?

I have to address and to work with every single number in the bracket.

`print(pm_list[0][0])` doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `print(pm_list[0][0])` is working for me!

Comment: what do you mean by 'working with' every single number?

Comment: What doesnt work about `print(pm_list[0][0])` it prints `1` for me so its accessing the individual number

Answer (score 0):

To use every number in the first result you can use a for loop.

```
for number in pm_list[0]:
   print (number)
```

Or if you want to do this for all results:

```
for result in pm_list:
   for number in result:
       print (number)
```